# When navigating between pages, scroll position being saved - Don't want this

Tags: next.js

Whenever I navigate to another page using  the scroll position is maintained. I want it to scroll to the top whenever I click on the link, but this is not happening.  I'm using NextJS 13.

`<Link href="/mypage">`

That's the code, I'm not overriding the "scroll" prop, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

I tried to override the prop with a true value, but still got the same result. If it helps, this is a server-component.